# Expo SDK Build failing while updating from SDK 47 to SDK 48

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a react native expo application build using Expo and I am using easto build my application for android. Recenty I had to update the SDK version of my app from SDK 47 to SDK 48, while updating the SDK version I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-48-ccb8302e231).

While building the application using the command `eas build` & selecting android, I am getting the error as shown in the image.
|[image]

In order to debug this issue, I tried running `npx expo-doctor` and below is result for the same:

```
$ npx expo-doctor
WARNING: We recommend using PowerShell or Bash via WSL 2 for development with Expo CLI on Windows. You may encounter issues using cmd.exe.

✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✖ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✖ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Detailed check results:

Expected package @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.2
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5
  (for more info, run: npm why @expo/config-plugins)
Advice: Upgrade dependencies that are using the invalid package versions.

error: unknown option `--check'
Advice: Use 'npx expo install --check' to review and upgrade your dependencies.

One or more checks failed, indicating possible issues with the project.
```

I tried updating the versions of both the packages, onces it completed, I ran `npx expo-doctor`, but I was still getting the same issue.

I tried updating the version of `expo-app-auth` as well but I was stil getting the same issue.

Anyone else facing this issue, what could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out the reason for getting that error, when I was updating my sdk version to SDK 48 with expo version 48 as well, expo-app-auth was being used by one of the dependencies which I checked using `npm ls expo-app-auth` `expo-google-app-auth@8.3.0 -> expo-app-auth@11.1.1`

and google-app-auth has been deprecated because so I had to replace it with `expo-google-app-auth` and then the build was getting built successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Try doing `npm i @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.2`, and then delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. Clear your npm cache too, and then try `npm i` again.

Also, what version of gradle are you using? If you're using gradle 8, you might be running into the issue outlined here: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-modules-gradle8-migration.md

Comment: Thanks for your response, I followed the steps as suggested but I am still getting the below error while building the app using eas build:
    * What went wrong:

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.

The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:

project ':expo-app-auth' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21


Anything else I can try to fix this issue?